# How to join two parts of an armature

Tags: armature

How can I connect those two parts of my little monster? I came extruding the bones down and now when I grab the torso it does not bring along the legs! Can you help me, please? All the rest is working fine.
 [image]

Comment: Thanks Moonboot. Can you tell me where to find a tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1):

Go in *Edit* mode, select the 2 hip bones, then the torso bone, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> > *Make Parent* > *Keep Offset*. Now the torso bone is the parent of the 2 hip bones, and the *Keep Offset* option allows them to keep their position and not stick to their parent.

Also, you need to assign an *Inverse Kinematic* constraint to your calves, it allows to reverse the influence of the bones so that the legs are not controlled by the base anymore, but by controllers that you will create and assign as *Targets*.

Comment: Thanks Moonboots. I had done that before posting my question. What so happens is that when I do that, When my character bows, the two legs follow it along, which should not happen.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: also, have you assigned an Inverse Kinematic constraint to your calves, it allows to reverse the influence of the bones so that the legs are not controlled by the base anymore.

Comment: Thanks again. When on pose mode I click on the calves bone the IK appears checked.

Comment: Please share your file, because it's hard to tell. Your calf doesn't seem to have any constraint as it is not green

Comment: If you don't like the way the rig controls with the legs parented to the torso, perhaps try making a new pelvis bone to which both legs and torso are parented